# What's the meaning of "personal correspondence"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, correspondence

"His personal correspondence is renowned in the Italian language"
- from an article about Niccolò Machiavelli

What is the exact meaning of "personal correspondence" in that context ?

Comment: Letters addressed to specific individual persons.

Comment: Yep, basically this means "letters" (as in those obsolete pieces of paper that people used to mail to each other before they discovered telephones and the Internet).

Comment: The modern equivalent would be "Tweets"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These would be letters Machiavelli wrote to friends and acquaintances but not as part of his official duties.  You may wish to read *Machiavelli and His Friends, Their Personal Correspondence*.  At the end of the 15th century and the beginning of the 16th, Machiavelli held diplomatic and military posts in the city-state of Florence, working as an official in the governmental apparat called the Chancery, and in this capacity he also wrote official correspondence.  Both types of letters dealt with politics and events of the day, but the latter would be written if not for the general public at least for official consumption.